# Chance to pick 3 balls out of 6 (with replacement, order doesn't matter)

Tags: probability, combinatorics

You have an urn with 6 numbered balls and you pull out 3 (with replacement). 
What is the chance of getting 3 different numbers when the order doesn't matter?

I have two solutions that both seem reasonable.

1. Looking at chances:
   Chance to pick the first ball: 6/6
   Chance to pick the second ball: 5/6
   Chance to pick the third ball: 4/6
   i.e. 20/36
2. Looking at possibilities (combinatorics):
   To get 3 different balls out of a urn with 6 when no number can be repeated and the order doesn't matter is the same as a lottery.

Therefore there are 
${6 \choose 3}$ = 20  possibilities.
Looking at *all* possibilities, I have 6*6*6 = 216.
i.e. 20/216

Which one is wrong and why?

Comment: Hint: how would the original question be different if order did matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The $20$ possibilities are without regard to order, while the $6*6*6$ considers the order you picked the balls.  This is exactly the factor $6$ between the answers. (First answer: 36;  multiply by 6, equals the second answer: 216) Your $20/36$ is correct.

Comment: But then it should be 56 possibilities, shouldn't it?
(6+3-1) over 3
or adding 36 possibilities with double or tripple numbers to the 20 I have already. Therefore I would end up at 20/56.

Comment: Each of the $20$ sets can be ordered in $6$ ways.  So there are $6*20=120$ ways to pick three different balls of $6$ with replacement, giving a chance of $120/216$

Comment: Okay, I understand that now, thank you! 
But still I wonder why it is not 56 possibilities for 3 balls out of 6 without order with replacement and double/triple numbers allowed (i.e. my denomninator)

Comment: There are $20$ combinations with the three distinct, $30$ with two of one and one of another, and $6$ with all the same.  But the chance of drawing each is not the same.  Because the $20$ with three distinct balls can come in six orders they are more likely.  $20*6+30*3+6=216$

Comment: Aaah, that is my problem! :) Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

First you pick one ball.

Then you pick a second ball. With `5/6` probability it is different from the first ball.

Then you pick the third ball. With `4/6` probability it is different from the first two.

`5/6 * 4/6 = 20/36`.